# 2D Battleship game demo. Suggestions and logic corrections welcome

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I am a novice programmer. I used a Random number generator to place ships. Placing ships needs few tweaks. Will use loops to make use of all the available space and also incorporate vertical placement.

Please review my code below and suggests any tweaks or logic corrections. 
Thank you.

```
var rn = 0;
var bx = by = cx = cy = 0;
var guess;
var guesses
var fsunk;
var bhit;
var c1hit;
var userchoices = [];
var battleship = []; //ship position stored in array
var cruiser1 = [];
var sunk = []; //ship status array 0 = floating, 1 = sunk
//var cruiser2 = [];
//var destroyer1 = [];
//var destroyer2 = [];
//var destroyer3 = [];
//var submarine1 = [];
//var submarine2 = [];
//var submarine3 = [];
//var submarine4 = [];

function rng() //Generates Random Numbers
{
rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
console.log("rn = " + rn);
return rn;
}
function spawn() //uses rng() to get x and y coordinates
{
bx = rng();
by = rng();
cx = rng();
cy = rng();
position();
}
function position() // ship positon generated
{
battleship[0] = ("" + bx + by);
battleship[1] = ("" + bx + (by + 1));
battleship[2] = ("" + bx + (by + 2));
battleship[3] = ("" + bx + (by + 3));
cruiser1[0] = ("" + cx + cy);
cruiser1[1] = ("" + cx + (cy + 1));
cruiser1[2] = ("" + cx + (cy +2));
}
function play() // onclick function
{
console.log("game start");
sunk[0] = 0; //battleship status flag
sunk[1] = 0; //cruiser1 status flag
bhit = 0; //battleship hit counter set to zero
c1hit = 0; //cruiser hit counter set to zero
console.log("sunk array = " + sunk[0] + " " + sunk[1]);
fsunk = 0; //fleet status
spawn();
position();
console.log("battleship coordinates" + battleship);
console.log("cruiser coordinates" + cruiser1);
game();
}
function game()
{
while(fsunk == 0)
{
    if(sunk[0] && sunk[1] == 1) //check if fleet is sunk
    {
    alert("enemy fleet sunk");
    fsunk = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        userinput(); //calls function to get users input
        if(battleship.includes(guess)) //checks if users guess is in battleship array
        {
            console.log("game.if") //just to see which clause is executing
            bhit++; //no of hits on battleship incremented
            if(bhit == 4)
            {
                sunk[0] = 1; //battleship status set to sunk
                console.log("battleship sunk");
            }
        }
        else if (cruiser1.includes(guess))
        {
            console.log("game.elseif")
            c1hit++; //no of hits in cruiser1 incemented
            if(c1hit == 3)
            {
            sunk[1] = 1; //cruiser1 status set to sunk
            console.log("cruiser1 sunk");
            }
        }   
    }
}
}
function userinput()
{
guess = prompt("Enter the grid coordinates. Do not use space. X-coordinates 
0-6, Y-coordinates 0-6.");
console.log("users input = " + guess);
while(guess < 0 || guess > 66 || userchoices.includes(guess)) //checks user input for repeated strikes or out of range. Suggest better way if possible. this is just bad code
{
    alert("You have entered an invalid coordinate.");
    guess = prompt("Try Again!");
}
guesses++; //increments no of guessess
userchoices.push(guess); //add users guess to array
return guess;
}
```

I have added comments to better explain each line of code. But feel free to ask for any explanations and do correct my logic wherever required. 
Thank you

Edit: I am currently working on incorporating more ships and vertical positioning. I am aware that requires major changes to spawn() and position(). I am also extending the board to the standard 10 X 10 grid and that also makes validating users input way easier.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service, and we expect you to have done your research and come up with an attempt at solving your own task.

Comment: I am currently working on it. I have some ideas. just needed o see if I made some errors or if someone has a  better logic which I am sure of.

Comment: It is not code review or code improvement service. If you have an error that you don't know how to fix, point the row and add error message. Otherwise I suggest you to look into some subject related tutorials.

Comment: And if you want code review, suggestions and critics, you better try some facebook game development groups. People there will rip your code into bites and add modifications or at least give some ideas.